# You're trying to build a job with no constraints, this is not allowed java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-studio

my app is working fine on 29 and above but below 29 i am getting this error , i dont want to use any constraint is their any way resolve this issue without using constraits

```
private fun scheduleService(sms: Sms) {

    Log.i("JobID","${sms.messages.messageId.toInt()}")

    val jobScheduler=    requireContext().getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
    val serializedSms  =    GsonUtils.serializeSms(sms)
    val componentName  = ComponentName(requireContext() , TodoJobService::class.java)
    val jobInfo = JobInfo.Builder(sms.messages.messageId.toInt() ,componentName)


    jobInfo.setPersisted(true )

    val persistableBundle = PersistableBundle()
    persistableBundle.putString(TodoJobService.JOB_KEY,serializedSms)

    jobInfo.setExtras(persistableBundle)


    jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo.build())


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Doesn't look like it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo):

> Prior to Android version `Build.VERSION_CODES#Q`, you had to specify at least one constraint on the JobInfo object that you are creating. Otherwise, the builder would throw an exception when building. From Android version `Build.VERSION_CODES#Q` and onwards, it is valid to schedule jobs with no constraints.

Can't you just set a constraint that doesn't matter? A low minimum, the backoff policy you prefer, something like that